# How would I get a File object from PhoneGap camera.getPicture?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova

This is probably simple and covered by some combination of functions in PhoneGap's "Camera" plugin, "File" plugin, or "File-Transfer" plugin. I understand the user can select a file with:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(function (fileURI) {

    // *** need help here ***

}, function ()
    // handle errors
}, {
    destinationType: window.Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: window.Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
    mediaType: window.Camera.MediaType.ALLMEDIA
});
```

I can also change to `destinationType: window.Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL` if that makes a difference.

My goal in the success handler is to get a File object (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Something like this should do it.

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(function (fileURI) {

    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(fileURI, 
        function(fileEntry){
            alert("got image file entry: " + fileEntry.fullPath);
            // fileEntry.file() should return a raw HTML File Object
        },
        function(){//error}
    );

}, function (){
// handle errors
}, {
    destinationType: window.Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: window.Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
    mediaType: window.Camera.MediaType.ALLMEDIA
});
```

Comment: An addition to this answer for anyone else looking to do this:  The Cordova FileEntry object has a file() method that returns a javascript File object.

Answer (score 1):

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(fileURI, function(fileEntry) { /* your code here */ });
```

Comment: resolveLocalFileSystemURI is deprecated. Please call resolveLocalFileSystemURL instead.

Comment: I got error for this `Uncaught TypeError: window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL is not a function`

Comment: My code is like billows `navigator.camera.getPicture((imgURI) => {
      window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(imgURI, (fileUri) => {
        const currentUpload = new Upload(fileUri.file());
        this.appConfigService.pushUpload(currentUpload, this.esCode);
        document.getElementById('msg').textContent = imgURI;
      }, err => {
        console.log(err, 'navigator.camera.getPicture3');
      });
    }, this.uploadfai, opts);`