# Start Photo-App with Phonegap and get FIle Name

Tags: android, ios, cordova, windows-phone, photo

How can I start the default Photo-App of a device using phonegap and get back the fileneam, where the photo is saved? Or alternatively, give it a file name to save it to?
For example, if the user taps "take picture", then his phones photo app will be started, he takes a picture, and saves it somewhere. Then the app gets the phots path and save it in a list.
It should work on Android, IOS and WP.

Comment: Check the phonegap capture plugin : http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#camera.getPicture

Comment: thx i'll have a look at it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how to get the path of the photo which has just been taken:

```
function get_photo_path(data) {
    var photo_path = data;
    return photo_path;
}

function take_photo() {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(get_photo_path, fail, {quality : 50});
}
```

Or refer to this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22156185/3381794